# is there a way to do something after a pipeline exceeded the timeout?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have automation tasks running on my pipelines sometimes something goes wrong and the operations get stuck, and they continue running until the pipeline gets cancelled due to timeout.

is there a way to do some recovering steps? sort of like a try catch?
like if a pipeline got canceled, is there a way to link another pipeline and that, that one do the recovering steps? I need to get the content of a txt file, it's a log, and if another process comes in, it replaces that log.

thank you for your help

Greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working! i was putting the timeout on the pipeline instead of the agent job, once i did that i added another agent job with the task to recover the file

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sharing, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way is to set up a recovery task (ex script) at the level of your environment and just after the deployment attempt / automation task.

After you configure a condition at the level of your recovery task for it to be launched only in case of failure of the previous task, it is the last option of the task:
Control options -> Run this task -> Only when a previous task has failed

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

[image]

You can also reduce the Timeout of the automation task to avoid long waits (also in Control options)

Comment: Hello, I have several like this, but when the pipeline gets cancelled it ignores everything and shuts it all out, thank you for your response

Comment: Otherwise a cron / cloud function which checks the cancels releases from the API to launch another release ?, difficult to maintain ^^